# extjs 4.1: Fix width of collapsible panels in table layout

Tags: extjs, extjs4, panel, extjs4.1

I am working on ExtJs collapsible panel in table layout.
Whenever I open the page the panel comes up perfectly fine (width wise).
Please check the below images
[image: Full application screen]
[image: Panel causing problem]

But when I collapse the panel, the width changes! 
See the below image:
[image: Collapsed panel]

A sample code to replicate this issue:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
title: 'Car Simple Tree',
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
layout: {
    type: 'table',
    columns: 2
},
items: [{
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'panel title',
    collapsible: true,
    titleCollapse: true,
    bodyStyle: {
        background: '#D9E5F3',
        borderColor: '#99BCE8',
        borderWidth: '1px'
    },
    scrollable: true,
    autoScroll: true,
    layout: {
        pack: 'center',
        type: 'hbox'
    },
    rowspan: 1,
    colspan: 2,
    width: '100%',
    items: [{
        text: 'Save',
        xtype: 'button',
        padding: 5
    }]
}, {
    html: 'Cell C content',
    cellCls: 'highlight'
}, {
    html: 'Cell D content'
}]
});
```

I have also created a fiddle with the same code.
[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ATechieDiary/8MjZa/)

Please help me in resolving this issue. 
I want the width of the panel to remain fixed whether it is collapsed or not.
But I **WANT** to set width in the terms of percentage and not fixed absolute number.

Answer (score 0):

To set the column width to '100%' use tableAttrs

```
layout: {
        type: 'table',
        columns: 2,
        tableAttrs: {
            style: {
                width: '100%'
            }
        }
    }
```

Also 'scrollable' and 'autoScroll' need not to be set to true since the column width will be '100%'

Comment: Tried this as well but no change. Still the collapsible panel as well as collapsible fieldset changes width whenever in collapsed state.

Comment: do you mean height changes when in collapsed state? Check this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2dm

Comment: Check this fiddle.. that's the real problem am talking about.. http://jsfiddle.net/ATechieDiary/8MjZa/